# Razor Pages Discovery and Authorization

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

I am developing a web app with ASP.NET Core 3.0 and Razor Pages. I want to add a feature, which allows users to search by page name - let's say that the user searches for 'password' and the results are 'Change Password', which is a Razor Page.

I imagine that page models would look like:

```
[SearchablePage(Name="Manage Account", Keywords="password,username,change")]
public class ManageAccountModel : PageModel
{
   ...
}
```

So far I managed to do Page discovery by injecting `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider` and looking for `PageActionDescriptor` items. This would show me all pages that are in the app.

I am not sure **how to get to the actual `PageModel` class** for each page so I can determine the value of my custom search attribute.

I am also trying to figure out **if the user is authorized** to see the page - whether is is coming from an authorize attribute or an authorization convention configured in Startup.cs.

Any help or pointers where to look will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

**Update**

I managed to find an `IAuthorizationService` provided from the framework - [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.0#iauthorizationservice). Now the trick is to retrieve all policies for a razor page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a working solution to this, which I've currently tested with Pages, not controllers and views.

**Required Interfaces**

- `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider` - Provides a list of all Razor pages.
- `PageLoader` - Loads a Razor page, resolves its security policies and class attributes.
- `IAuthorizationService`- Determines if the user is authorized to a policy.

**Steps**

Get a list of all razor pages.

```
var pageDescriptors = _descriptorProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items
  .OfType<PageActionDescriptor>()
  .ToArray();
```

Loop through the pages and load each one:

```
var compiledPage = await _pageLoader.LoadAsync(pageDescriptor);
```

At this point you can do some processing based on attributes that are added to the page model. Note that **any attribute that you add to the page model class will be automatically resolved in the `EndpointMetadata`**, no need to do custom reflection work!

```
var pageMetadata = compiledPage.EndpointMetadata
  .OfType<PageMetadataAttribute>() // My custom attribute.
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that policies and authorization will be added to the Razor page metadata in the form of an `AuthorizeAttribute` instance.

Extract the authorize attributes, loop through them and evaluate.

```
var authorization = compiledPage.EndpointMetadata
  .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
  .ToArray();

foreach (var auth in authorization)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth.Policy))
  {
    var authResult = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(
      _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User,
      auth.Policy);

    if (!authResult.Succeeded) return; // Do stuff here.
}
```

Comment: In our app we do something similar, getting all PageActionDescriptors, loading the compiled page and then identifying razor pages with a certain attribute. We have updated to C# 6 not long ago and I noticed today that LoadAsync has been marked deprecated in favour of another LoadAsync overload that additionally requires an EndPointMetadataCollection. Not a problem right now, but might become one down the road. I have not found much guidance on this change, might you possibly have some pointers to add on how to address this or were to read up on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the following page that lists out all of the routes in my webapp. That I use to diagnose endpoints. Might be useful to use as a starting point. I'm not sure how you would get authorization info.

```
public class RoutesModel : PageModel {
    private readonly IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider;

    public RoutesModel(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider) {
        this._actionDescriptorCollectionProvider = actionDescriptorCollectionProvider;
    }

    public List<RouteInfo> Routes { get; set; }

    public void OnGet() {
        Routes = _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items
                .Select(x => new RouteInfo {
                    Action = x.RouteValues["Action"],
                    Controller = x.RouteValues["Controller"],
                    Name = x.AttributeRouteInfo?.Name,
                    Template = x.AttributeRouteInfo?.Template,
                    Constraint = x.ActionConstraints == null ? "" : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x.ActionConstraints)
                })
            .OrderBy(r => r.Template)
            .ToList();
    }

    public class RouteInfo {
        public string Template { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Controller { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public string Constraint { get; set; }
    }
}
```